# How to get the Javascript messages from android webview

Tags: javascript, android, dom, android-webview, webchromeclient

Hey guys I wanted to inject some code into a webview and see whether the code has succeeded. I've tried to override the onConsoleMessage method of WebChromeClient but it only reports whether the code is an uncaught reference

```
public boolean onConsoleMessage (ConsoleMessage consoleMessage){
    System.out.println(consoleMessage.message());
}
```

I only get messages like:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: noob is not defined
```

When I execute a valid command like

```
document.getElementById("mainPage").innerHTML = "Hello Dolly.";
```

I would want to somehow know that the command succeeded or failed. The content of mainPage div changed fine but I got no messages from the onConsole method whether the command finished with success or not.
Any idea what I could do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Giggled at `noob is not defined`. Have you tried connecting to it via Chrome?

Comment: `onConsoleMessage` will only work when you do something with the console such as `console.log`. You could place `console.log` *after* your statements to make sure it didn't crash or something.

Comment: there has to be something that indicates that javascript has succeeded any ideas?

Comment: @JohnSmith There's not. When you consider the fact that, ideally, all of your code works then it would be incredibly expensive to check if it *didn't* work. You could wrap your code in a `try-catch` block though. `try { doSomething(); } catch(err) { console.log(err); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That method is a callback, it does not do what you want.

Try this

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Hey there!')");
```

to inject javascript.

Then you set up a custom WebViewClient to the WebView and override [onReceivedError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError%28android.webkit.WebView,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to detect any JS errors.

Theres also this method [evaluateJavascript](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) which might be useful to inject JS and detect if it succeeded. Your script string would look like this:

```
(function() {
    try {
        //do something
        return "ok";
    } catch(err){
        return "error";
    }
})();
```

So you would call it like this:

```
mWebView.evaluateJavascript(<above script here>, new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        if("ok".equals(s)){

        } else {
            //error
        }
    }
});
```